# How do I insert data in firestore in array of string?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

[Here is want I want to do by code and insert in realtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PkDi.png)

[I Want to take userName from here and want to add in above, array of string userName_*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTmMp.png)

- Create collection("room")
- Add randomNumber to "room" Collection
- getCurrentUser name ADD to array of users in firestore field
- Keeps checking and update in recycler view if new user is found in room -> randomCode -> inRoom (userName)

I want to update the recycler view and show users only if code (randomNumber) generated from start activity (Host) matches with the join activity

[Start activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKIyE.jpg)
[Join activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TjzD.jpg)

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with additional details? I'm not getting which room must the user should be added.

Comment: Room is the collection in firestore where I want to store data of the user based on condition that if code generated by Host (mainActivity) and entered by player (JoinActivity) matches then I want to get all the users of that particular code and show in recycler view.

For reference image check end of ques. [edited: added screenshots]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a combination Set with Merge:true to push id's to a document (create if not created) to get this result.

How you manage the document ID wasn't defined clearly, but I assume you have some internal logic, provided is an example of how to push a string into an array.

```java
DocumentReference FirestoreRef = db.collection("room").document("myID");

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("userList", FieldValue.arrayUnion("user_id"));
FirestoreRef.set(docRef, map, SetOptions.merge());
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro it's working fine as per my requirement I can't vote you because (You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded)

Comment: One more logic I want how to handle
if there is two people in my game with same name...?
I think for this I must add UID instead of username and from that UID (in users collection) I should fetch data and update recycler view!

Comment: correct, a uid is a global identifier that is used to define one user from another, if you need to populate the user data, it is suggested to pull from a public profile of some sort. I personally prefer a mega collection of profile names/pictures, this way I reduce reads on the users end